# Pathologic relative path on multisite

Tags: 7, uri, input-formats

Old multisite subsite relative path to image (in block/Full HTML with CKeditor and on localhost/XAMPP):

```
/sites/site1.localhost/files/image.png
```

New multisite path (what I'm trying to achieve):

```
/sites/site2.localhost/files/image.png
```

So, in Full HTML input settings for Pathologic, we select the 3rd option Relative path and add lines:

```
/sites/site1.localhost/
/sites/site2.localhost/
```

And nothing happpens, it just strips the /sites/site1.localhost/ from path and now the path to image is just:

```
/files/image.png
```

How do I make it the `/sites/site2.localhost/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved running SQL query in phpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE field_data_body  SET body_value = REPLACE(body_value,'src="/olddirectory','src="/newdirectory');
```

Source article: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/changing-image-paths-drupal-subdirectory-installation